# width based on difference between two time values

Tags: lua

When a function is run, it saves two values:

1. os.clock() + int
2. os.clock()

so example values:

1. 2795.100
2. 2790.100

*(5 second difference)*

so the moment this function is called, I need to draw a bar, and at this moment it would be drawn at 0% width, when os.clock() returns 2792.550 it should be at 50% width, os.clock() returns 2795.100 it should be at 100% width.

**I am trying to find the math logic to:**

1. based on the difference between these two values, decide how many pixels one % would be, so I can use os.clock() to calculate the bar length

I have been struggling with this but I have no code of use to show. Since in example values there's a 5 second difference between the two values, and I want to draw a bar that is at 0% width that grows to 100% over 5 seconds.

Comment: "how many pixels" depends entirely on how big the bar is to start with. But the answer is "a percentage of the width of the bar to match the percentage of the time slice that has elapsed".

Comment: yes that's what I am trying to find. when this function is run, a 350 px bar appears, and "attached" to it, I need a bar that goes from 0 to 350 px as in 0 to 100%, based on the time that has passed.

Comment: Right. That's just math. Percentage is percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just basic math.

```
local interval_start = 2790.100
local interval_end   = 2795.100
local current_value  = 2792
local bar_max_width  = 350

--                        how far current value is from start  / entire length of interval of allowed values
local fill_percentage = ((current_value - interval_start) / (interval_end - interval_start))
local fill_width      = bar_max_width * fill_percentage


print(fill_percentage, fill_width)
```

Feed one of those values to whatever drawing facility you use.